# error 403: insufficient permissions Google Gmail API

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

[quickstart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsw2o.png)
[creating and sending email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOQSk.png)

'''

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://mail.google.com/']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('/Users/akshaywork/Downloads/credentials2.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
        labels = results.get('labels', [])

        if not labels:
            print('No labels found.')
            return
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'''

'''

```
from __future__ import print_function

import base64
from email.message import EmailMessage

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def gmail_send_message():
    """Create and send an email message
    Print the returned  message id
    Returns: Message object, including message id

    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
    """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)

    try:
        print("1")
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        print("1")
        message = EmailMessage()
        print("2")
        message.set_content('This is automated draft mail')
        print("2")
        message['To'] = 'akshay@work'
        message['From'] = 'akshay@work'
        message['Subject'] = 'Automated draft'
        print("3")
        # encoded message
        encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()) \
            .decode()
        print("3")
        create_message = {
            'raw': encoded_message
        }
        print("4")
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        send_message = (service.users().messages().send
                        (userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
        print("4")
        print(F'Message Id: {send_message["id"]}')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        send_message = None
    return send_message


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gmail_send_message()
```

'''

every time I run the command to create and send the email(copy pasted nearly verbatim from the google documentation), I get

> <HttpError 403 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">"

Added all the permissions I could think of from the google api dashboard, enabled every single gmail related scope, and both scopes here are mail.google.com, so I don't see where the insufficient permission could have come from.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code here not as a link

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran the code once and then changed the scope adding the send scope and haven't reauthorized the code

delete token.json and try again

Comment: I tried that a few times, fixed it for a lot of people but unfortunately not me

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem,

it turns out you don't need two separate files, you can just add the email generation and sending within the same try catch statement as polling everything. just make sure you have all of the imports.